# Querying hive using Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to execute a query in hive using Airflow HiveOperator. My code is below :

```
import datetime as dt

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'dime',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 3, 24),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

hql_query = """USE testdb;
CREATE TABLE airflow-test-table LIKE testtable;"""

load_hive = DAG(dag_id='load_hive',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='0 * * * *')

hive_copy = HiveOperator(task_id="hive_copy",hql=hql_query,hive_cli_conn_id="hive_cli_default",dag=load_hive,)

hive_copy
```

While executing I am getting error:

> No such file or directory: 'hive': 'hive'

P.S. Airflow installation is in other machine than where HIVE is.

Comment: Did u find any solution for it?

Comment: I didn't work on it later on. But one pointer I can give is, as my airflow is in another machine ,it doesn't have hive cli. So you can try keeping airflow in a machine having hive cli.